# Xamarin Forms: Tabbedpage icon and title overlapping

Tags: xamarin.forms, overlapping

I have created a tabbed page in my xamarin forms project. Using `android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"` option I added it on the bottom of android device. But Currently the icon and text are overlapping in tabs.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**TabbedPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartWCM;assembly=SmartWCM"
            BarTextColor="#0091da"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            BarBackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#0091da"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#0091da"
            x:Class="Proj.MyTabbedPage">
</TabbedPage>
```

**TabbedPage.xaml.cs**

```
//I have added all the child from xaml.cs like below.
var homePage = new Pages.HomePage(false)
            {
                Title = "Home",
                Icon = "ic_home_xx.png"
            };

            var topicsPage = new TweetsTopicsPage()
            {
                Title = "Announcements",
                Icon = "ic_topics_fill_xx.png"
            };

            var groupPage = new TweetsGroupPage()
            {
                Title = "Class",
                Icon = "ic_group_xx.png"
            };

            var ABPage = new DirectoryPage()
            {
                Title = "Contacts",
                Icon = "ic_addressbook_xx.png"
            };
            Children.Add(homePage);
            Children.Add(topicsPage);
            Children.Add(groupPage);
            Children.Add(ABPage);
```

Already found the same issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3983). Is there any way to solve this issue from xaml.cs? Because I have a lot of conditions in xaml.cs.

**To GiampaoloGabba**

I added the custom renderer from [here](https://gist.github.com/LynoDesu/64904b6d143892cf14a60a32798a36bb) but still the text is overlapped with icon, see the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due the "shift mode" that is activated when there are 4 or more tabs.
You can try to fix it with an effect, check if this answer resolve your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56545801/9823528

Comment: I added the custom renderer but still the text is overlapped with icon, please see the screenshot added in the question.

Comment: i strongly suggest to use the Routing Effect implementation over the custom renderer, to avoid unnecessary reflection. with the effect you can choose what mode suits your needs: LabelVisibilityAuto, LabelVisibilitySelected or LabelVisibilityUnlabled. I'm investigating the overlapping issue, i have not encountered it with the Routing effect posted in the answer linked

Comment: Actually, I don't have this issue initially, I have added a high-resolution picture in homepage. After that, this problem started. From the homepage, I am opening the tabbed page.